# Android - add a listener to .setDoneText in CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment

Tags: android

I want to add a listener when the user click "ok" button in the calendar dialogue but I am facing a problem in writing it, I tried the following:

```
CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment calendarDatePickerDialog = new CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment()
                .setOnDateSetListener(this)
                .setPreselectedDate(date.get(Calendar.YEAR), date.get(Calendar.MONTH), date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                .setDoneText(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        RadialTimePickerDialogFragment rtpd = new RadialTimePickerDialogFragment()
                               // .setOnTimeSetListener(this)
                                .setStartTime(10, 10)
                                .setDoneText("Yay")
                                .setCancelText("Nop");
                        rtpd.show(fragmentManager,"");
                    }
                });
```

the problem is in the .setDoneText i don't know what is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if no such function in `CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment`:

```
public CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment setDoneText(String text, View.OnClickListener listener)
```

You have to use the method:

```
public CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment setDoneText(String text)
```

for changing "Ok" button text and:

```
public CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment setOnDateSetListener(OnDateSetListener listener)
```

for registering the callback, when it is pressed:

```
CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment calendarDatePickerDialog = new CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment()
            .setOnDateSetListener(this) // <- passing callback
            .setPreselectedDate(date.get(Calendar.YEAR), date.get(Calendar.MONTH), date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
            .setDoneText(getResources().getString(R.string.ok)); // <- passing "ok" button text;
```